# How do I get the id of the created order

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, strapi, nuxt-strapi

I am using Strapi with Nuxt and I would like to redirect to the new order it was created after successfully posting the order to Strapi. What I'm looking for is the equivalent of `mysql_insert_id()` in the PHP world.

##### code example

```js
try {
    const neworder = await this.$strapi.$orders.create(this.neworder)
    console.log(neworder)
    if(neworder !== null) {
        this.$router.push({ name:'order-id', params: neworder.id })
    }
} catch (error) {
    this.error = error
}
```

I can see the new id on the console log:

[image: console log]

How do I access the returned id and pass it to `this.$router.push`'s params? I tried using 'id' same as it shows on the console but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I'm going to leave this open in case it helps someone else.

redirect ($router.push) should be like this:

```
this.$router.push({ name:'order-id', params: {id: neworder.id }})
```